# Sorting by Self Referencing Relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Assume the following model. Note the self-referencing relationship "parent".

```
class Widget(object):
    __tablename__ = 'widgets'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('widgets.id'), nullable=True)
    parent = relationship("Widget", remote_side=[id])
```

I am attempting to formulate a query which will allow me to sort by "parent.name". Specifying joins on the query doesn't seem to have any affect on the SQL that is generated and executed.

I would be more specific about what I've tried thus far, but the thing is, I've thrashed all day on this and have pretty much exhausted the available documentation.

Any WAGs on what I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [SA docs for self-referencing structures](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#self-referential-query-strategies) - in particular look at the declaration of `Node` just before the self-referential section begins.

I'm not an expert on these hierarchical setups (they can get a little dicey) but it looks like you have set up your relationship opposite of the examples in the docs. That is not to say you are doing it wrong, but rather that the `Node/Parent/Children` example in the docs seems to map to what you're trying to do. You *should* be able to set up your `Widget` in the same manner as the `Node` example, get the `parent` into your query, and then do the sort.

Comment: Doh! That is exactly what I needed. I can't tell you how many times I looked at that, I guess it just didn't sink in.